# WCF Duplex Service Channel Close

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an application based around a WCF Duplex service. I have problems when the user "Restarts" the work the application does... under the hood, the client side closes the connection to the WCF service and creates another. The Service contract is defined like so...

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="net.tcp://namespace.MyService",
    SessionMode=SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract=typeof(IServiceCallback))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void DoWork();
}


public interface IServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void SendMessage(string message);
}
```

The implementation is defined as:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false,
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>();
        callback.SendMessage("Hello, world.");
    }
}
```

The configuration for the client is as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="net.tcp" receiveTimeout="02:00:00" sendTimeout="02:00:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService/MyService"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="net.tcp" contract="ExternalServiceReference.IMyService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Config for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcp" sendTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" >
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour" name="MyService.MyService">
    <endpoint address="MyService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp" name="net.tcp" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
    <endpoint binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="net.tcp" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

In the client's contructor:

```
var callback = new CallbackImplementation();
_context = new InstanceContext(callback);
_proxy = new MyServiceProxy(_context);
```

I'm trying the following before I establish a new connection:

```
        try
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.ReleaseServiceInstance();
                _context.Close();                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Abort();
            }
        }
```

The issue I see is that the _context.Close() call always times out and throws an exception. Although I'm then aborting the channel, this feels wrong to me, and I believe it's the cause of freezing in my application. Does anybody know why the Close() call fails?

**EDIT:** I missed something earlier regarding my callback implementation that might be relevant. It looks something like this:

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, 
    UseSynchronizationContext = false, 
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class CallbackImplementation : IServiceCallback
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        // Do something with the message
    }
}
```

The exception message is "The ServiceHost close operation timed out after 00:00:30.  This could be because a client failed to close a sessionful channel within the required time.  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.". There's no inner exception.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding an `OnClose` event handler. See if the event gets fired on the `callback` server side.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that: both the Closing and Closed events are firing.

Comment: But the service is still timing out? Have you tried setting the `CloseTimeout` on the binding?

Comment: Yes, I've set the closeTimeout on both ends and the same issue is occurring.

Comment: Could you please post the exception? Also, a quick solution to application responsiveness would be to do this: `Task.StartNew(()=>{_context.Close();});`

Comment: Edited. But doesn't your solution simply fire off the Close() method and let the exception exist only within its thread? Seems like masking the problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: You can assign the above statement to a `var` then check the `AggregateException` and put exception logic there, or put the entire try-catch block into the delegate (the part between the brackets).

Comment: Try adding this config on the client: `<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add maxconnection = "200" address ="*" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>`

Comment: I think this might be a bug in WCF... or, it's related to trying to close a net.tcp connection, which is implemented kinda funny, I wish you hadn't solved this by going to dual http, and somebody answered definitively about net.tcp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not only concurrency, but the binding type.

Making sure the concurrency mode of both the service and the callback was a step in the right direction. But changing the binding from netTcpBinding to wsDualHttpBinding has finally fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue right off, but I often find that running traces on both the client and server and examining the results usually points me to the solution. Put this in your .config files (client and server), make sure the path points to a folder that exists. Run your app, get the failure, then shut everything down and run SvcTraceViewer.exe to read the results.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\TracingAndLogging-service.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried receiveTimeout="infinite", to see if you still receive the error. You may just find that it's not the timeout creating the error. Have you thought about creating a base client class that automatically keeps the connections alive till physically closed?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, it could be a deadlock caused by the use of `ConcurrencyMode.Single`.

What could be happening is that the server is trying to call back to the client while it is still processing the original request (or vice versa).  So server is trying to call back to client, but client is blocking because it is still waiting for a response from the server.  Hey presto, deadlock and eventually a timeout.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx