# WPF Client keeping WCF session alive

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

As on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368501/wcf-duplex-service-channel-close/24598590#24598590) I had some issues with a WCF service. That's been fixed by using multiple concurrency mode in the callback and service, and by changing the binding to wsDualHttpBinding.

Now I have another issue: if I close the WPF Client application, I am unable to start another instance. It simply runs in the background and will never display a window. I have to restart the service to start the WPF application again, which will not be feasible when the service is running on a server.

I am definitely closing the proxy when the application closes, using the following code:

```
        try
        {
            if (_proxy != null)
            {
                // Calls some server cleanup.
                _proxy.Disconnect();

                _proxy.InnerDuplexChannel.Close();
                _proxy.Close();

                _proxy = null;
            }

            _context.ReleaseServiceInstance();
            _context.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (_proxy != null)
            {
                _proxy.InnerDuplexChannel.Abort();
                _proxy.Abort();
                _proxy = null;
            }
        }
```

What causes the WPF client to keep a server session/instance alive? Is there a way to avoid it or even force it closed?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to restart the service to start the WPF application again..."?

Comment: Does your self hosted service open a WPF application at startup? I hope not, since that would be so wrong on so many levels ...

Comment: The WCF service is hosted in a Windows Service, and unless I restart it the WPF application will hang. Then I can start the WPF application. No, the service does not open a WPF application, that's just crazy.

Comment: Where is the service instance declared?

Comment: What you're saying is the Dispose() method of a class called Client. The constructor for that class declares the proxy instance, which is of a type generated automatically from an added service reference.

Comment: This gets stranger. I've now ascertained that the WPF client application is certainly running in the background - it's able to communicate with the service, so there's no issue with sessions. However none of the windows are being rendered! The service is also holding on to more memory than it should be.